# Is this, by any chance, an already existing pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

We have a config.ini file with methods associated to tables, something like this:

```
[assoc]
people = getPeopleTable
food = getFoodTable
```

in our main program we instantiate a database object and we call them like this:

```
output = getattr(self.db, 'getTable')(config.get('assoc',table))
```

and in our database class we have the methods to fetch each table, and, `getTable`, which looks like:

```
def getTable(self, table):
  table = getattr(self, table)()
  return table
```

Is this by any chance a type of design pattern? Sorry if it seems stupid, this subject is new to me.

Comment: The closest paradigm I see here is [declarative programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). Not a pattern per se, but a practice.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a Software Design Pattern. It is missing every single thing that makes a Pattern:

- an *Evocative Name*
- *Context*
- a description of the conflicting *Forces* that both would pull you towards using the Pattern as well as push you away from it
- a description of the *Problem* the Pattern solves
- a description of the *Solution* the Pattern provides, including
- *How* the Pattern solves the problem and
- *Why* the Pattern solves the problem (and also why some other related Patterns *don't* solve the Problem)
- *Examples* of applying the Pattern, both in high-level form (e.g. diagrams of the design) and in code (ideally, in multiple languages)
- *Known Uses*: a Pattern is only a Pattern if it is a *common* solution to a *recurring* problem, here you should describe where you found the pattern in different systems
- *Related Patterns (and Anti-Patterns)*: Patterns have relationships with other Patterns (for example, Iterator and Subject/Observer are category-theoretical duals, Model-View-Controller is often used together with Subject/Observer, Front Controller and Page Controller are alternatives, and so on).
- … and probably some more I forgot.

Comment: Sorry, I might have not expressed myself properly, I was wondering if this is by any chance an already existing pattern.

Comment: @Onilol Then your question is written in a misleading way. You might want to rewrite it.